# JOIN with OR condition taking long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one select process where in select query I am using join like below.

```
select * from Table1 t1

Left join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID

OR (t1.col1     = t2.col1

AND t1.col2     = t2.col2

AND t1.col3         = t2.col3

AND t2.ID IS NULL
)
```

This OR condition is making insert process very slow. Is there any other way i can make OR condition to another join to make process fast.

Thanks
R

Comment: You could make 2 selects with union all

Comment: Your query posted here isn't an insert. Also, performance problems are specific to the table structure, indexing and data. None of this is posted or explained in your question. From what you posted there is only one possible answer. "It depends".

Comment: Show us the execution plan and table structures. Probably covered index will help, if you reduce selected columns.

Comment: I can't show real table and columns names here. But i have created all the indexes which estimated execution plan shows me. My question is Can i split OR condition to another Join.

Comment: Can the id field of the second table be null?

Comment: Yes. That is why we have to bring data of t2.ID is null based on OR condition

Comment: @James. Union All won't work. It merges both the select records

Comment: @Ritesh can you show an example with data where the UNION ALL approach won't work?  In principle it should, and has the benefit that two execution plans (potentially using different indexes, etc) can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, you could use a second join instead of the `OR`:

```
select * from Table1 t1

Left join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
left join table2 t3 on 

 (t1.col1     = t3.col1

AND t1.col2     = t3.col2

AND t1.col3         = t3.col3

AND t3.ID IS NULL
)
```

Anything you're including in your insert from table2 will need to be coalesced with the second alias (coalesce(t2.col1,t3.col1)).

Now, whether this will do anything for your performance or not is another question entirely.

Comment: I tried this. But changing OR condition into Join giving me less records than before.

Comment: Id name admitDate dischargeDate Status PaidAmt BilledAmt CalcID claimId CategoryId OutlierAmount Threshold
23 99221 1/20/2014 1/24/2014 3834 8346.41 67917 2491 1537364 2088 0 0
23 99221 1/20/2014 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Answer (score 1):

OR condition usually affect performance to some extend that is true. You can use this:

```
Select * from table1 t1 Left Join table2 t2 on t1.ID = T2.ID
Union All
Select * from Table1 t1 Left Join Table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3 AND t2.ID IS NULL
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: +1 : `UNION ALL` should be fine, no need to use `UNION` with its de-duplication overhead.  Either `t1.id = t2.id` from the first query *(in which case `t2.id IS NOT NULL`)*, or `t2.id IS NULL` from the second query.  As `t2.id` is being included in the results; no row from the first query can ever match any row from the second query.

Comment: @Ritesh - Then there is something that you're not telling us.  Please include example data where this query does not meet your needs.

Comment: Yes you are right. I though you would need de-dup results but Union All should be fine as Mat said.

Comment: Let me try this again and I will get back with example data. Thanks all

Comment: sample result after Union All

Comment: Id name admitDate dischargeDate Status PaidAmt BilledAmt CalcID claimId CategoryId OutlierAmount Threshold
23 99221 1/20/2014 1/24/2014 3834 8346.41 67917 2491 1537364 2088 0 0
23 99221 1/20/2014 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL

Comment: Union All somehow creating duplicates rows bit few columns chnages, which is not our requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can use union all. Note the inner join in the first select - this makes both selects truly complementary with regard to the records which match by any of the OR'ed conditions in the original. If both fail, the respective records from `Table1` are preserved by the left join in the second select.

```
    select *
      from Table1 t11
      join Table2 t21 on ( t21.ID = t11.ID )
 union all
    select *
      from Table1 t12
 left join Table2 t22  on (        t22.ID   IS NULL
                               AND t22.col1 = t12.col1
                               AND t22.col2 = t12.col2
                               AND t22.col3 = t12.col3
                             )
         ;
```

Comment: Good spot on the first `LEFT JOIN` needing to be an `INNER JOIN` (+1)